# Copy several directories to another directory

Tags: docker, copy, cp

How would you copy several directories to a destination directory in docker? I do not want to copy the *directory contents*, but the whole directory structure.

The `COPY` and `ADD` commands copy the directory contents, flattening the structure, which I do not want. That is, if these are my sources:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── aaa.txt
│   └── uuu.txt
├── b
│   ├── ooo.txt
│   └── ppp.txt
└── c
    └── jjj.txt
```

I want this to be deployed to the docker image:

```
code/
├── a
│   ├── aaa.txt
│   └── uuu.txt
├── b
│   ├── ooo.txt
│   └── ppp.txt
└── c
    └── jjj.txt
```

I know I can do this:

```
ADD a /code/a
ADD b /code/b
ADD c /code/c
```

But this is, compared to the linux `cp` command, too verbose. It also creates unnecessary layers.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
COPY ./ /code/
```

It will copy everything from the current folder into the */code* folder of your image.

So then you can create *.dockerignore* file to prevent of adding other files/directories then *a*, *b* and *c*. For example *d*, *e* and *f* are other directories in the current folder which should not be in the result image then content of the *.dockerignore* file will look like:

```
Dockerfile*
d
e
f
```

Disadvantage of this approach is that it will copy also *.dockerignore* into the */code* folder.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not suit my needs. I want to manually specify which directories to copy. In the current folder there is lots of stuff which hos no business in going to the docker image.

Comment: @dangonfast I understand but I'm afraid that this is not possible by one `COPY` or `ADD` command.

Comment: Your workaround with the `.dockerignore` is probably a good compromise. I will give it a go.

Comment: @dangonfast Yes, you named it exactly - it is not perfect solution but only workaround ;-)